# Emulator for vscode for Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

How to set up android emulator for vscode?
I have been working with flutter in vscode but couldn't find android emulator option in vscode.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install android studio and the SDKs to get an android emulator. You can run the app with your physical device and mirror the phone using [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/) .